# How to access data from json wrapped with xml characters?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

i have a response that i wanted to map to interface and send it back to client but it throws always undefined properties error , Any idea what is implemented wrong here ? I wanted to send back to client `soapenv:Body` object

main.ts

```
public getData(args: ICarrierTrackingParam, data: any): Promise < ICarrierTrackingResult > {

    console.log("DATA>>>>>>", data.Details["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]);
    // const parsedJson: ICarrierTrackingResult;

    // parsedJson = JSON.parse(data);


    const trackResponse: any = data.Details["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"];
    // const response: ICarrierTrackingResult  = data.Details.Envelope.Body;

    console.log("BODYY", trackResponse);

    // const trimmedResponse = response[soapenv:Envelope][soapenv:Body][trk:TrackResponse];
    return Promise.resolve(this.getDetails(args, trackResponse));
}

interface.ts



export interface ICarrierTrackingResult {
        Details: EnvelopBody;
    }
    export interface EnvelopBody {
        "soapenv:Envelope": Envelope;
    }
    export interface Envelope {
        $: $;
        Header: string;
        Body: Body;
    }
    export interface $ {
        "xmlns:soapenv": string;
    }

    export interface Body {
        "soapenv:Body": string;
    }
```

data

```
{
    "Details": {
        "soapenv:Envelope": {
            "$": {
                "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            },
            "soapenv:Header": "",
            "soapenv:Body": {
                "trk:TrackResponse": {
                    "$": {
                        "xmlns:trk": "http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Track/v2.0"
                    },
                    "common:Response": {
                        "$": {
                            "xmlns:common": "http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0"
                        },
                        "common:ResponseStatus": {
                            "common:Code": "1",
                            "common:Description": "Success"
                        },
                        "common:TransactionReference": ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `getDetails` look like? `args` is not defined.

Comment: args are coming from other methods that is working as expected just problem is with the response

Comment: My apologies. It looks like the problem could be in your getDetails function, since trackResponse contains valid properties.